# An elephant in the room

Tags: meaning

I like elephants. A friend of mine was very excited therefore to tell me an elephant joke this morning. Problem is I don't get it, and she didn't hang around long enough to explain it to me. What is the language gag here? Here's the joke (I think):

> A friend of mine gave me an elephant for my room the other day. "Wow", I said, "An elephant. Gee, thanks very much." "Oh, don't mention it".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_in_the_room

Comment: @michael.hor257k Nope. Still don't get it ...

Comment: The elephant in the room is the obvious problem/issue nobody wants to mention (don't mention it). ***The play is on the "don't mention it" part*** of the joke.

Comment: @Josh So, erm, no. I still don't get it.

Comment: It's a play on the idiom "an elephant in the room," which is an important topic or issue that people are keen to ignore. The advice to "Don't mention the elephant in the room" will mean something like, "Don't mention the obvious thing that everyone knows is problem, because we're all trying to ignore the fact that it's a problem... and we don't want you to bring up the fact that we're ignoring it." This joke is funny(?) because the friend gives you an elephant and then says "don't mention it," in the sense of "No problem for the gift" but also in the sense of the literal elephant in the room.

Comment: DON'T TALK ABOUT THE ELEPHANT IN THE ROOM. It's a standard way of referencing the fact that people often refuse to talk about things that are obviously important. In BrE we also have the somewhat less PC version [Don't Mention the War!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfl6Lu3xQW0), as mercilessly satirised by *Fawlty Towers*.

Comment: It is a joke on the double meaning  of  "don't mention it".

Comment: @Araucaria: I've voted to close (as "trivial"), but since you apparently understand enough to think of *Don't mention the war!* as being a related usage, I'm now starting to wonder if you're asking in good faith.

Comment: @AraucariaMan It's a joke because it is funny. I don't think this is a question about English anymore.

Comment: @MDHunter Is your comment an answer in disguise?

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/don%27t+mention+it

Comment: "A traveler passing through Yuma / Told an elephant joke to a puma. / Now his bleached bones lie / 'Neath the cold Western sky / For the puma had no sense of huma."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about humor not the English language.

Comment: Voting to reopen because there is a language understanding problem going on here.

Comment: Joke explanations are off topic

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, and to everybody, to help explain why this is so closable. I'm not sure about your question about 'comments can be off-topic' because those two concepts don't go together here. Only questions can have that attribute.

Comment: @Mitch Oh, have you been drinking? This question was closed three months ago.

Comment: @Araucaria I've only been drinking as much as you. You just edited this question an hour ago, presumably to bump it to the top of the queue to get exposure again. I'm just reiterating that your edit didn't really change the situation, that it is still asking for a joke explanation. I'm just explaining why it was closed and should be kept closed. There is a case to be made for language joke explanations to be on-topic, but that is a question for meta.ELU.

Comment: @Araucaria ??? I don't understand where you're coming from. This question popped to the top of the queue, a couple hours ago, I looked at it and thought I'd add something I didn't already see to the comments. I'm not trying to 'get' you. Just trying to explain.

Comment: @Araucaria Have the comments answered your actual question ('Can someone explain how this is a joke?'). If not, come to chat and we can help explain, If so, then you should be happy already. Either way, it's very unlikely to be reopened.

Comment: @Mitch Yes, this is  big exposure question as you point out. Huge. You are right. I spend my free time trying to get my closed, tongue-in-cheek questions a  higher view number in the right hand box at the top of the question.  You got me. I resign - not., I edited this title because I wanted it to relate exactly to the punch-line of the joke. So shoot me.

Comment: @Mitch There's really no need to be obtuse. The well-meaning but tongue-in-cheek question was closed. There was no effort on anyone's part to get it re-opened as you could see. There was no recent re-open vote on my part or anyone else's. The whole thing is done and dusted. You and I have a vaguely bad historical relationship. Perhaps be a grown-up and don't be attracted to my posts or comments like a moth. There's no reason for you to comment on this post